# How can I bump down an inline image by 1px but not the rest of the line?

Tags: html, css

I am needing an inline image to position 1px below baseline. How can it be done?

Thanks
Mike

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A relative position should do the trick:

```
img.icon {
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also fake it by editing your image:

add as many transparent rows above your current image as needed and you're done!